# 404 error in eclipse when running servlet on server tomcat with Macbook PRO

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am trying to develop a very simple web app in Eclipse using tomcat as the web container. My problem is that when i type localhost:8080 in the browser it comes up with the tomcat web page, so it works. But when I try to run my servlet on server through Eclipse i get the 404 error saying that the requested resource is not available.
My index.html works without problems but when I click on button to compile my servlet I get the 404 error.Please help me solving this problem. Here attached the index.html and login.java text. Sorry, I'm Italian so part of the text are written in Italian but you should be able to understand anyway.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pagina iniziale del sito</title> </head> <body>
    <h1>Benvenuto</h1>
    <p>Effettua il login per accedere</p>
    <form action="login" method="post">
        Username: <input name="user" type="text" /><br />
        Password: <input name="pass" type="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form> 
</body> </html>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pagina iniziale del sito</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Benvenuto</h1>
 <p>Effettua il login per accedere</p>
 <form action="login" method="post">
  Username: <input name="user" type="text" /><br />
  Password: <input name="pass" type="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Would you please add your web config? It could be that you did not properly configure the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Add your webapp to Tomcat, to do that, right click Tomcat and then "Add and Remove...". If you already do that, try Tomcat>Clean....
The webapp should be access with

```
http://localhost:8080/your_project_name
```